# Improper Restriction of XML External Entity Reference - Java with DocumentBuilderFactory

Tags: java, xml, external, veracode, xxe

I've been trying to resolve the Veracode "Improper Restriction of XML External Entity Reference" flaw. I looked up the issue online and a found a few suggestions on how to resolve it, namely:

- Set the features mentioned in the [OWASP cheat sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XML_External_Entity_(XXE)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#JAXP_DocumentBuilderFactory.2C_SAXParserFactory_and_DOM4J)
- Set XMLConstants features mentioned [here](https://www.blackhat.com/docs/us-15/materials/us-15-Wang-FileCry-The-New-Age-Of-XXE-java-wp.pdf)

To my dismay, Veracode still reports the flaw and I'm frankly lost on how to proceed. I have Java 8 installed and using JRE 1.8.

Here's a snippet of my code (edited following VGR's suggestion):

```
InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(reader);
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

dbFactory.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl", true);
dbFactory.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities", false);
dbFactory.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-parameter-entities", false);
dbFactory.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false);

dbFactory.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD, "");
dbFactory.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_SCHEMA, "");
dbFactory.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_STYLESHEET, "");
dbFactory.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true);

dbFactory.setAttribute(XMLInputFactory.SUPPORT_DTD, false);  
dbFactory.setAttribute(XMLInputFactory.IS_SUPPORTING_EXTERNAL_ENTITIES, false);

dbFactory.setXIncludeAware(false);
dbFactory.setExpandEntityReferences(false);

DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
org.w3c.dom.Document doc = dBuilder.parse(inputSource);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (SAXException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: `XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING` is a feature, not an attribute.  It should be passed to the `setFeature` method.

Comment: I tried passing it to the `setFeature` method but that didn't resolve the problem. I added two more features (edited in the post), `SUPPORT_DTD` and `IS_SUPPORTING_EXTERNAL_ENTITIES`. Let me know what you think.

Thanks!

Comment: You may want to read [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/XMLConstants.html) for each of those attribute constants.  The value for each ACCESS_EXTERNAL_\* attribute is not supposed to be boolean; it’s a string, specifically a comma-separated list of allowed URI protocols, or the empty string to forbid all external accesses.

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a look at the documentation,

With what you say, passing an empty string to forbid all external access should do the trick right?

Comment: It’s certainly a step in the right direction.

Comment: Great. I'll try that and let you know what happens :)

Comment: I did what you suggested but the veracode static scan still reports the same flaw. I'm starting to suspect that the scan isn't even detecting the changes that I'm putting. The line number that it reports (where the flaw allegedly is) never changes despite the changes that I make...am I missing something here?

Comment: I haven’t used Veracode, but I’ve experienced this frustration with similar security analysis tools that don’t point out what exactly is wrong or missing.  Try setting the old feature names, the ones prefaced with ‘Xerces 1’ or ‘Xerces 2’ in the the first link you provide, in addition to the features you are currently setting.  They shouldn’t make a difference functionally, but Veracode’s analysis criteria may be out of date and may require them.

Comment: I believe I tried that before but it didn't work. I'll give it another shot however and let you know what I get. Thanks!

Comment: I just tried it. Same problem. It still reports the same line number despite making sure I change what's on that line with every scan. This does not make sense.